# Why does my code keep making a string with one or two letters instead of three?

Tags: python-3.x, genetic-algorithm

I am learning how to use genetic algorithms. I found this (reletively, clearly) simple exercise that walked me through the basics of how to do it (https://blog.sicara.com/getting-started-genetic-algorithms-python-tutorial-81ffa1dd72f9).

The goal of the exercise is to crack a 'password' that is given in the function. It then does its whole algorithm thingy. First it makes a population of random strings of characters the length of the 'password'.

```
def generateOrganism(length):
  possible_chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
  i = 0 
  result = ""
  while i < length:
    i += 1
    character = random.choice(possible_chars)
    result += character
  return result


def generatePopulation(sizePopulation, password):
  population = []
  print('Starting Algorithm')
  i = 0
  while i < sizePopulation:
    population.append(generateOrganism(len(password)))
    i += 1
  return population
```

Then the fitness (determined by how close the word is to the password) of each word is then checked as shown:

```
def fitness (password, test_word):

    if (len(test_word) != len(password)):
        print("taille incompatible")
        return
    else:
        score = 0
        i = 0
        while (i < len(password)):
            if (password[i] == test_word[i]):
                score+=1
            i+=1
        return score * 100 / len(password)
```

And that is called be the computePerfPopulation function which makes a dictionary of the word and its fitness.

```
def computePerfPopulation(population, password):
  populationPerf = {}
  for individual in population:
    populationPerf[individual] = fitness(password, individual)
    if fitness(password, individual) == 100:
      print("EUREKA, WE HAVE CRACKED THE PASSWORD. IT'S '", individual, "'")
      return 'Done'
  print(populationPerf)
  return sorted(populationPerf.items(), key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
```

Then that dictionary is passed to the selectFromPopulation function which selects the words with the best fitness and a few random words for 'breeding'.

```
def selectFromPopulation(populationSorted, best_sample, lucky_few):
  nextGen = []
  for i in range(best_sample):
    nextGen.append(populationSorted[i][0])
  for i in range(lucky_few):
    nextGen.append(random.choice(populationSorted)[0])
  random.shuffle(nextGen)
  return nextGen
```

Then the words are breeded with the functions below. **This is where the problem arises.**

```
def createChildren(breeders, num_of_children):
  nextPopulation = []
  for i in range(0, len(breeders) // 2):
    for j in range(0, num_of_children):
      nextPopulation.append(createChild(breeders[i], breeders[len(breeders) -1 -i]))
  print(nextPopulation)
  print(len(nextPopulation))
  return nextPopulation



def createChild(individual1, individual2):
  child = ""
  for i in range(len(individual1)):
    if (int(100) * random.random()) < 50:
      child += individual1[i]

    else:
      print(i)
      print(individual2)
      child += individual2[i]
  return child
```

Then some random words might get mutated with the function below, but thats not entirely important. Then the whole thing is looped until the password is recieved

```
def mutatePopulation(population, chance_mutate): # population is a list

  for i in range(len(population)):
    if int(random.random() * 100) < chance_mutate:
      population[i] = mutateWord(population[i])
  return population


def mutateWord(word):
  possible_chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'

  index_mods = int(random.random() * len(word))
  if index_mods == 0:
    word = random.choice(possible_chars) + word[1:]
    print(word)

  else:
    word = random.choice(possible_chars) + word[index_mods+1:]

  return word
```

Sometimes the whole project works as its supposed to and the 'password' is found. But occasionally I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 146 in <module>
    project(100, 'lol' 10, 10, 5, 5)
  File "main.py", line 137 in projcet
    remakePopulation = createChildren(newBreeders, num_of_child)
  File "main.py", line 33 in createChildren
    nextPopulation.append(createChild(breeders[i], breeders[len(breeders) - 1 - 1]))
  File "main.py", line 49, in createChild
    child += individual2[i]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

When I was investigating the issue, I started printing out the list produced by the createChildren function as it was making it, (I will give the total project code below) and noticed that occasionally (on the second loop or above, never on the first) some of the words would be ***one or two characters.*** I suspect that this is because, when I loop it again, I insert the new population into the computePerfPopulation function and the new population isn't the same size as the original one, throwing off the indexes? (I hope that made sense)

I have no real idea what causes the problem, and would really appreciate if someone could tell me what's going on. (I know this has been long winded but bear with me) Also if you have any pointers on making this code nicer, and if you could give me a good resource for genetic algorithm implementation, I would be very grateful.

(If you take all this code here and run it, after a few tries it should show you the error and such)
Here is the full project code:

```
import random
import operator


def mutatePopulation(population, chance_mutate): # population is a list

  for i in range(len(population)):
    if int(random.random() * 100) < chance_mutate:
      population[i] = mutateWord(population[i])
  return population


def mutateWord(word):
  possible_chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'

  index_mods = int(random.random() * len(word))
  if index_mods == 0:
    word = random.choice(possible_chars) + word[1:]
    print(word)

  else:
    word = random.choice(possible_chars) + word[index_mods+1:]

  return word




def createChildren(breeders, num_of_children):
  nextPopulation = []
  for i in range(0, len(breeders) // 2):
    for j in range(0, num_of_children):
      nextPopulation.append(createChild(breeders[i], breeders[len(breeders) -1 -i]))
  print(nextPopulation)
  print(len(nextPopulation))
  return nextPopulation



def createChild(individual1, individual2):
  child = ""
  for i in range(len(individual1)):
    if (int(100) * random.random()) < 50:
      child += individual1[i]

    else:
      print(i)
      print(individual2)
      child += individual2[i]
  return child




def selectFromPopulation(populationSorted, best_sample, lucky_few):
  nextGen = []
  for i in range(best_sample):
    nextGen.append(populationSorted[i][0])
  for i in range(lucky_few):
    nextGen.append(random.choice(populationSorted)[0])
  random.shuffle(nextGen)
  return nextGen



def computePerfPopulation(population, password):
  populationPerf = {}
  for individual in population:
    populationPerf[individual] = fitness(password, individual)
    if fitness(password, individual) == 100:
      print("EUREKA, WE HAVE CRACKED THE PASSWORD. IT'S '", individual, "'")
      return 'Done'
  print(populationPerf)
  return sorted(populationPerf.items(), key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)



def generateOrganism(length):
  possible_chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
  i = 0 
  result = ""
  while i < length:
    i += 1
    character = random.choice(possible_chars)
    result += character
  return result


def generatePopulation(sizePopulation, password):
  population = []
  print('Starting Algorithm')
  i = 0
  while i < sizePopulation:
    population.append(generateOrganism(len(password)))
    i += 1
  return population



def fitness(password, test_word): # fitness function of the algorithm

  if len(test_word) != len(password):
    badFit = 0.0
    return badFit

  else:
    score = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(password):
      if password[i] == test_word[i]:
        score += 1

      i += 1
  if test_word == password:
    print("SUCCESS")

  fit = (score * 100) / len(password)

  return fit



def project(population_size, password, best_sample, lucky_few, num_of_child, chance_of_mutation):
  password = str(password)
  population = generatePopulation(population_size, password)
  populationSorted = computePerfPopulation(population, password)
  #print(computePerfPopulation(population, password))
  breeders = selectFromPopulation(populationSorted, best_sample, lucky_few)
  nextPopulation = createChildren(breeders, num_of_child)
  nextGeneration = mutatePopulation(nextPopulation, chance_of_mutation)
  while True:
    i = 1
    newPopulationSorted = computePerfPopulation(nextGeneration, password)
    if newPopulationSorted == 'Done':
      break
    newBreeders = selectFromPopulation(newPopulationSorted, best_sample, lucky_few)
    remakePopulation = createChildren(newBreeders, num_of_child)
    nextGeneration = mutatePopulation(remakePopulation, chance_of_mutation)
    print(nextGeneration)
    print(len(nextGeneration))
    input('Press enter to continue')
    i += 1
```

Comment: There are several places in your code where you loop through one variable and use the counter to get the index in another variable. You are bound to run into index errors whenever you do that.
The for loop inside of createChild and the else statement inside of it is one example.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim Do you know how to fix it? I can't think of any. This might be why my problem is happening.

Answer (score 0):

In the part

```
def mutateWord(word):
    possible_chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
```

Probaly is in a single text instead of an array?

Like:

```
def mutateWord(word):
    possible_chars = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

Thats a shot!

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: You remembered to change the parts of the code that use the string value to Array?

Comment: I changed it to 
```possible_chars = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']```

Comment: i ment like that:
`if index_mods == 0:
    word = random.choice(possible_chars) + word[1:]
    print(word)`

Comment: You had to change the entire code, not just the part of text to an array.

Comment: Do you know how I would select a random item in the array? I was contemplating changing the code but didn't know how to do it. I was thinking random.randint(0 , len(possible_chars)), but that would return me a float not an integer

Comment: Search for "How to select an item in array in python"
The thing you gonna do is using like:
`for(i) in range(len(possible_chars)):
  word = random.choice(possible_chars[i] + word[1:]
  print(word)`
Something like that

Comment: It doesn't do anything, and I think I know why. The mutate function comes after the 'children' of the words are made. My issue is that in the **createChild** function it comes up with the issues aforementioned